# Eclipse import existing project now showing up

Tags: java, eclipse-luna

I am trying to import a project into workspace, but surprisingly that option is not showing up.

[image]

Comment: Which eclipse version are you using?

Comment: That's pretty strange. Has this happened recently after any kind of update or was it showing up like this since the beginning?

Comment: It was working 30 mins ago.

Comment: OOPS I don't know what fixed the problem system restart or  in frustration I think I was clicking on Export project.

Comment: Well,  above screenshot is for Export project not import project.

Comment: Yes! i was wrong! shall I delete this question or keep it ?